# Entity Framework error: The Entitycontainer name must be unique

Tags: entity-framework

I have searched around and I have not been able to find an answer for this particular issue. Most of the results that come up for the Entity Container name have something to do with .dll files not being cleaned or duplicate edmx's with the same container name.

I have 4 applications that access the same db over 3 different environments which all need their own connection string. 1 console app, 1 web app and 2 web services. In order to remove duplication of the edmx file across all the apps, I pulled it out into its own library which I import into each of the above apps passing a string to the constructor which the library then uses to determine which connection string to use when creating the db connection.

For the web app and the console app, it works fine. However the 2 web services are in the same solution and what I have found is that once 1 of them establishes a connection, the other will get the Entity Container name must be unique exception and fail.

Based on what I have been able to find on the forums, it appears that I need to create a second edmx with a different container name so that both web services can access the db. What I would like to confirm is that is in fact what I need to do and that there is no other workaround for this issue.

I dislike the idea of creating an entire edmx just for a web service and it would seem there should be a way to share the connection across these two services through the imported .dll.

Also I don't quite understand why the other applications can access the db through the same container name and only the 2 web services have this issue?

In the library I have a constructor that returns an `ObjectContext` like so:

```
public partial class Entity : ObjectContext
public static Entity Create(string env)
{
    switch(env)
    {...}
    return new Entity(connectionString from case statement);
}
```

and in the client applications I have a class called `DbConnection` that has a static method that gets the environment variable from the `app.config` or `web.config` then gets the `ObjectContext` like so:

```
public static Entity CreateDBConn()
{
    string env = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["env"].ToString();
    return Entity.Create(env);
}
```

I would really love to understand what is going on and why the other applications can use the same container name but the web services cant, also what is the best "fix" for this particular issue. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is similar to an error message I have received for nested web.config files creating connection strings of the same name - which sounds like it could be the case in your project setup? If so you can using the `<clear/>` directive, e.g.:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <clear/>
    <!--Used to clear inherited connection strings for when this is deployed as a child application. (Avoids the name collision)-->
    <add name="DbContext" connectionString="MyString" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: I accepted this as an answer for the problem above. For some users this might solve their problem. In the end I created a second edmx file for the second web service to solve the problem as I could not find a way to programatically clear the connection string outside of the app.config file.

Answer (score 0):

That might work for a normal config file set up, however I do not use the Web.config file for my connection string. I use SqlConnectionStringBuilder and EntityConnectionStringBuilder to create the connection string. The data values that would normally be pulled from the web.config or app.config files are kept in a separate xml file that is common to all the apps then parsed in by a class I created to create the connection string.

The purpose of the class is to create a re-usable  connection string that submits a request to the external library for an ObjectContext connection without having to continually reparse the xml file.

I'll look into the /clear command and see if it will fit programmatically with what I'm trying to do.

In order to make this work, I ended up creating a second edmx file with a different namespace which resolved the conflict. I would like to revisit this issue however so if I find a better way to resolve this, I'll post.

Thanks!